Default 'None' turning to 'NULL' after flyway migration
In the current DB (10.3.15-MariaDB) I have multiple columns that are NOT NULL with Default None. After flyway migrating the tables to a new DB (same MariaDB version though) all of these columns are NOT NULL with Default NULL. For example, a table created like
| accounts_deleted | CREATE TABLE `accounts_deleted` (
  `account_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

will show up as:
MariaDB [main]> describe accounts_deleted;
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type                                                                                                                                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| account_id               | int(11) unsigned                                                                                                                    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |

What might have caused this? Is there some strictness setting I am not aware of?
Searched the MariaDB documentation, downgraded to the exact same MariaDB version - was expecting that the discrepancy was from different versions.

There is no such thing as None in SQL - None (in Python) is represented as NULL in SQL. Is the default value the string None?

did you possibly mean 'None' as text string?

I have a column defined as ``account_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL and in phpmyadmin it shows None under default. On the new db when I go in the console (did not set up phpmy admin there) the same column shows NULL under default.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, use the same way to check for details on both systems

do note that mariadb 10.3 reached end of life almost a year ago and no longer receives security updates; consider it insecure and plan to upgrade to a long term support version (10.11, 10.6) or the current stable version (11.3) as soon as possible.

You are misinterpreting your tools.  The column has no default.  It is not possible to set a NULL default for a NOT NULL column.
There is no None value in mysql; presumably phpmyadmin is trying to indicate that there is no default value.
show create table yourtablename is the best way to see how a table is set up.  Other ways may show values for various column settings whether or not they actually apply.

Ok - the column has no default value, seemed pretty straightforward to me. I guess my confusion arises from the following:
the show create gives me:
| accounts_deleted | CREATE TABLE `accounts_deleted` (
  `account_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

and the describe gives:
Field: account_id Type: int(11) unsigned Null: NO Key: PRIMARY Default: NULL
